# How to run an application in background for windows mobile 6?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am working on an application for windows mobile 6.
I need to run my application in background .
which i am doing using

```
private void app_menu_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       this.Hide();         
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

now i need to again launch my application to stop the application but i am not able to do this.
can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Some options spring to mind:

- If you need to process window messages: Create an invisible 0-sized message-only window.
- If you need to listen to state changes in kernel synchronization objects: Don't create a window, but wait for those events, in a loop if needed, instead.
- If you need to listen to both: Create the message window and use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects to react to both window messages and kernel events.

For the service part of the question: You cannot create a true service in C#, you need to go native for that to happen. You can get "almost there" by using my points above, but a true service has special perks in the OS and you can't get near them in C#.